# Circular queue modeling

Tags: scheduling, constraint-programming, logical-constraints, queuing-theory

Let

- $P$ be a set of *discretely interruptible* processes/tasks;
- $T_i \in \mathbb{N}$ be the running time of process $i \in P$; And
- $\tau \in \mathbb{N}$ be the maximum amount of time a process can use the machine, per turn.

We aim finding a *circular* scheduling for $P$, satisfying the time limit $\tau$ and completing the demanded time $T_i$, $\forall i \in P$.
A *circular* scheduling is given as a sequence $S$ of tasks, in such a way that, if process $S_l$ ($l$-th process in the sequence $S$) is placed to be executed at time $t$, then at time $t + 1$ the process to be executed must be the one indexed at:

- $\arg \min_{l \leqslant k \leqslant |P|: \text{ process $S_k$ wasn't completed till time $t$, and $\tau$ not exceeded}} \{ k - l \}$, i.e. the process after (or at) $l$, in the sequence, which still has pending execution time; Else
- $\arg \max_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant l - 1: \text{ process $S_k$ wasn't completed till time $t$, and $\tau$ not exceeded}} \{ l - k \}$, i.e. the process before (or at) $l$, in the sequence, which still has pending execution time.

Let's consider the example below:

| $P$ | $T$ |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $3$ |
| $2$ | $4$ |
| $3$ | $2$ |
| $4$ | $3$ |

Let's assume, we have $\tau = 2$, and a scheduling for $P$ given by the sequence $S = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$. Then we would have the following picture.

| $t$ | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ | $5$ | $6$ | $7$ | $8$ | $9$ | $10$ | $11$ | $12$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $P$ | $1$ | $1$ | $2$ | $2$ | $3$ | $3$ | $4$ | $4$ | $1$ | $2$ | $2$ | $4$ |

In time

- $t = 2$, process $1$ is chosen because it still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 3$, process $2$ is chosen because it comes right after process $1$ in the sequence, still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 4$, process $2$ is chosen because it still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 5$, process $3$ is chosen because it comes right after process $2$ in the sequence, still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 6$, process $3$ is chosen because it still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 7$, process $4$ is chosen because it comes right after process $3$, still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 8$, process $4$ is chosen because it still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 9$, process $1$ is chosen because it comes right after process $4$ in the (circular) sequence, still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 10$, process $2$ is chosen because it comes right after process $1$ in the sequence, still have pending execution time, the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process, and process $1$ has no pending execution time;
- $t = 11$, process $2$ is chosen because it still have pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process;
- $t = 12$, process $4$ is chosen because, in the sequence, it is the process right after the previous process with pending execution time, and the time limit $\tau$ still being respected for this process.

I would like to know how to model this problem through Constraint Programming.

Answer (score 1):

$0 \le x_{p,d} \le T' \quad \forall p \in P \ \forall d \le T$.
$d$ is the index of slots covering required duration of each job as in column $T$.
For e.g. for job $1$ d.v. will be $x_{1,1},x_{1,2},x_{1,3}$
$x \in Z$
$T'$ is the max time available, here it will be $12$

Constraints
$x_{p,d+1} - x_{p,d} \ge 1$

$x_{q,d}-x_{p,d} \ge 1 \quad \forall q \in P \ \ \& q \neq p$
The above two pairs of constraints can be implemented using 'all-different' constraints

$1-z_{p,d} \le x_{p,d}-x_{p,d-1}-1 \le T(1-z_{p,d})$

$\sum_d z_{p,d} \le \tau \quad \forall p$

where $z$ is a binary

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I do not understand the constraint $x_{p,d+1} \geqslant x_{p,d} + 1$, since it doesn't take into account the limit $T^{'}$.

Comment: Hello @MatheusDiógenesAndrade, I am just trying to force the solver to ensure $x$ variables take different variables from discrete set of $T=\{1,2,3,...12 \}$